# Facebook bidding Integration with MAX in Android

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network, applovin

I am trying to integrate MAX mediation patrner as facebook bidding partner in Android application. I can't find simple solution for integrate in mobile application. I integrate facebook audience integration successfully but can't bid with MAX.

Answer (score 0):

In all ad integrations - you're only allowed to use one "mediator" whose SDK will be in charge with "managing" the waterfall / bidding of other SDKs. You can easily integrate [FAN bidding into MAX](https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/mediation-adapters?network=FACEBOOK_MEDIATE) (not to be confused with FB bidding kit).